# Are there simple http services out there to check domain name availability

Tags: java, html

Im looking to call a simple http service from my Java servlet to check the price an availability of domain names from my site.

Basically, i want to do something like this checker here... http://www.123-reg.co.uk/

I know i can just to a get on the target url and parse the response, but I'm looking for an exising service this just gives me an XML response. Even a webserivce if available.

Has anyone come across any companies that expose their domain checkers as a service?

Thanks.

Comment: there's something you should be aware of... some disreputable registrars will actually buy domain names that people have checked for availability but didn't immediately buy.  That way, when you come back later to actually buy it, they can charge you more.  Also it requires that you buy it from their service and not some other.  You might lose your domain just by checking to see if it exists.

Comment: @rmeador This risk can be mostly mitigated by using a trusted/reputable whois server for your lookup.

Comment: @meador: You are referring to the practice of "domain tasting". According to http://icann.org/en/announcements/announcement-12aug09-en.htm  the practice has been all but stamped out.

Comment: Sorry. I confused the terms. The practice is called "domain name front running"; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_front_running  The ICANN changes do however help to address this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) lookup. Here is a GNU licensed [Java whois package](http://www.skytouch.com/soft/java/whois.html). And here is [another Java whois package](http://www.jscape.com/inetfactory/whois.html).

Comment: Cheers mate! One thing.. I would like to be able to quote a price for registering the domain. Do you know if this would be possbile.

Comment: That depends on what registrar you choose. The price can vary. What registrar will you be purchasing domain names through?

Comment: different registrars will likely give you different prices.  You'll have to pick who you want to buy it through and ask them.

Comment: To be honest, I'd purchase through the first one that offers an easy http service that I can call :-)

I usually use 123reg but the price seems to be similar over different providers anyway.

Comment: Basically im trying to put a little box on the screen that lets users check the availability of a domain name and the price, then order it. After that I would go and buy it for them from the company and setup the dns servers as needed etc.

Answer (score 0):

you gotta have a try with [domainr](http://www.domai.nr) and its [api](http://domai.nr/api).